# Release method in char device driver is executed after a delay

Tags: android, kernel, linux-device-driver

I have an existing char device driver. When I call close() from the userspace, the function returns immediately with a success, but the actual printk statements inside the release(close()) function in the device driver is executed later as a Async task. So the userspace only tells the kernel to close the device and returns without actually closing it. Actual close happens after sometime. Why is there a delay in the execution. Is there a way to make this call synchronous.

Comment: `but the actual printk statements inside the release(close()) function in the device driver is executed later as a Async task.` - More likely that `printk` output is transmitted into the kernel log with a delay. The better way for check delays in `release()` is to execute `rmmod <module>` immediately after the `close()` the file, defined in that module. `rmmod` may succeed only after the `release()` operation.

Comment: What I am doing is that I click start immediately after I click close. The start() method executes before the statements release(close()) method executes. What I suspected was that the userspace tells the kernel to close the file descriptor and returns true. The kernel then starts an Async task to actually close the file descriptor. The start method executes before this async task. The printk statements inside start() method are printed first and then the printk statements in close() method are printed.

Comment: What do you mean by "I click start" or "I click close"? `close()` is a function, which should be *called*. Or do you have some GUI wrapped it?

Comment: I have a GUI wrapped up. When I click start in GUI, the open function in kernel will be called. When I click stop in GUI, the close(release) function in the kernel will be called. Kernel calls are mapped in device driver and those corresponding functions in device drivers will called. The delay happens in device driver functions.

Comment: How do you tell the delay happens in driver module, Post your close() and how userspace accesing function() to understand supporters better.

Comment: I'm not sure if it applies to your case, but the _open file description_ (corresponding to the `struct file` object in kernel-land) resulting from a call to `open()` has a reference count associated with it that has an initial value of 1. The `release()` file operation will not be called until the reference count is decremented to 0. `close()` will decrement it. `dup()`, `dup2()`, etc. will increment it. `mmap()` will also increment it and needs a corresponding call to `munmap()` to decrement it. `fork()` or `clone()` with `CLONE_FILES` will double it. Process exit will reduce it as necessary.